# Office 365 and Office 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-integration

I can't open Word, Excel file from SharePoint in client application Word and Excel (Office 2013). When I click to the file, SharePoint inform me that I don't have any client application. From Word or Excel I can open this documents.

Can you have similar problem?
What can I do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, that you didn't configure Web Apps for SharePoint 2013. [This post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/23/configuring-office-web-apps-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) may help you to configure it.

Comment: Web Apps working fine. I can't use Word, Excel client application.

Comment: Oo, I had similar problem after installing some windows updates, unfortunatelly I don't know correct way to solve this problem, it problem gone away after couple of days for me and I didn't research it.

Comment: But I need solution for this problem - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed SP Designer 2013 preview? If you have - uninstall and it will correct the problem

Comment: I don't install SP designer 2013

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Office 365 site is on Sharepoint 2013 and not 2010?
Mine Office 365, for example,  is on Sharepoint 2010 Online.

If it is on 2010 then you cannot hope that it can be aware about Office 2013 components and products...

Comment: The site is on SharePoint 2010 Online - I have info that "...can't find application consistent with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation"